# border-left with 1px from the maintable

Tags: css

I want in a table in html a border left. 
Here is the table

```
.weTable td{
border-color:#dcdcdc;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
}
```

This is for the table cell and this has the table

```
border-left: 15px solid #548dd4;
```

My problem is I want a vertical line left and its not a straight line on this way.

**Now:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4uiA.jpg]

**What I want:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKZJX.png]

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Whats the difference between the two images? Apart from some widths and a different screenshot position..?

Comment: Try table { border-collapse: collapse; }

Comment: I want just that the line is straight
if the border is bigger than goes the line into the centrum of the cell

Comment: The blue bar goes one pixel down
if the borde is bigger than more and more
I want it just straight but its not working on this way which i discribed
border-collapse is not working @SKeurentjes

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that borders meet at an angle so unless you remove the border from the top you cannot get straight 'joins'.

As an alternative, you could add extra `padding-left` to the cell and use an inset box-shadow like so.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  margin: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
table td {
  width: 50px;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-left: 65px;
  position: relative;
}
table td {
  box-shadow: inset 15px 0 0 lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table class="shadow">
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one?

```
table {
border-left: 15px solid #548dd4;
border-spacing: 0px;}
```

Comment: I want it for a cell not the complete table
in a cell its not working. Than it looks like the first picture